# Opening packages from jar file to run on another program

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath

How do I run this package on my program? 
I want to run a program but need this jar file to correspond.
How do I open this package so it can run on my other code?

```
package enhanceduc;

import unitconv.UnitConverter;

public class EnhancedUnitConverter {

public double returnFeet(String input){
    String[] h = input.split("'");
    return Double.parseDouble(h[0]);
}

public double returnInches(String input){
    String[] h = input.split("'");
    return Double.parseDouble(h[1]);
}

public double returnHeight(String input){
    double ft = returnFeet(input);
    double in = returnInches(input);
    double m = UnitConverter.feetToMeters(ft);
    m += UnitConverter.inchesToMeters(in);
    return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to work on the subject of the question :). Please explain the real problem, are you not able to access UnitConverter? Getting any errors?

Comment: "open this package" is not right statement or right thing you are trying to do.

Comment: I basically need to import this code onto another. But I keep getting these errors ConvertHeight.java:1: error: package enhanceduc does not exist

Comment: you need to create the file in "ConvertHeight.java" in folder "enhanceduc". Then execute it using java -classpath <path of the lib> enhanceduc.ConvertHeight

Comment: where do I create folder? In the same place where ConvertHeight.java is located?

Comment: Yes, Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674046/how-to-compile-java-code

Comment: @SandeepJindal : i dont think there is any need to put ConvertHeight.java in any folder as ConvertHeight.class is a part of jar file. Having said that, raul all that you need to do is make sure that the jar file is present in the classpath and you are all set to compile this

Comment: My Bad. Think ConvertHeight as EnhancedUnitConverter. But @zerocool, the EnhancedUnitConverter needs to be in folder enhanceduc.

Comment: I got it, it had some some bad coding from another coder.Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the jar that contains this class is on the classpath at compile time. If you were launching the java compiler (javac) [on the command line](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/), you could include jars on the classpath with the argument -cp.

Otherwise, if you are writing java using an IDE (which I strongly recommend), how you include the jars into the IDE's compile classpath may differ depending on the IDE, but your IDE of choice should be able to support a dependency management tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to handle that for you.